# Does finite kth moment imply lesser moments are finite?

Tags: moments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof that if higher moment exists then lower moment also exists](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26454/proof-that-if-higher-moment-exists-then-lower-moment-also-exists)

For a random variable $X$, lets say I know $E[X^k]$ is finite and I know that $E[X]$ is finite. Can I say that all moments between first and kth moment are finite?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes. In fact, you don't even need to know that $E[X]$ is finite: if you know that the $k$-th moment $E[X^k]$ is finite, then all lower moments must be finite.

You can see this using Jensen's inequality, which says that for any convex function $\varphi$ and random variable $X$,
$$\varphi(E[X]) \leq E[\varphi(X)].$$
Now, suppose we know that $E[X^k]$ is finite, and we want to check whether $E[X^m]$ is finite where $m < k$. Let $\varphi(X) = X^{k/m}$. Since $k>m$, this is a convex function. Then by Jensen's inequality,
$$(E[X^m])^{k/m} \leq E[(X^m)^{k/m}] = E[X^k].$$
We know that $E[X^k]$ is finite, so $(E[X^m])^{k/m}$ must also be finite, and so $E[X^m]$ is finite.

In summary: given that the $k$-th moment is finite, all lesser moments must also be finite.

Comment: This lacks rigor, starting from the very formulation of Jensen's inequality... which should say something to the extent of "... provided the necessary expectations are finite".

Comment: @StasK Guilty as charged. I was written an exposition, not a textbook.

Comment: Thanks guys, I tried searching for this but was having trouble coming up with the right queries.

Comment: k = 9, m = 3, X^3 is not convex. Do we require non-negativity of X?